# Ranks of elliptic curves over cubic fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, rational-points, magma

We are writing a paper on the ranks of elliptic curves over cubic fields. The curves of different torsion subgroups are created by the formulas in Jeon et al. and by our new parametrizations.

> D. Jeon, C. H. Kim, Y. Lee, *Families of elliptic curves over cubic number fields with prescribed torsion subgroups*, Mathematics of Computation, V. 80, 273, January 2011, p. 579-591, JSTOR: [41104715](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41104715).

The current rank records over quadratic fields are well documented in

> A. Dujella, *High rank elliptic curves with prescribed torsion over quadratic fields*, [web page](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/torsquad.html).

The information about the ranks over cubic fields seems to be scarce, the only resource known to us is Theorem $7$ and Table $5$ in

> J. Bosman, P. Bruin, A. Dujella and F. Najman, *Ranks of elliptic curves with prescribed torsion over number fields*, Int. Math. Res. Not. IMRN 2014 (11) (2014), 2885-2923, [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0252.pdf).

> **Question:** Are there any other resources for the ranks of elliptic curves over cubic fields?